# Como calcular parcelas (R$) e preencher inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Gostaria de ajuda para implementação do cálculo das parcelas e preenchimento/criação dos inputs de acordo com o número de parcelas.

Código abaixo e no https://jsfiddle.net/wnm3jhr7/:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
 
 $('#condicao-pag').on('change', 'select', function() {
  if($(this).val() == 1){
   $('#parcelamento').show();
   /*Calcular valor das parcelas (2x, 3x e 4x) e preencher inputs*/
   $('#parcelas').show();
  }
  else{
   $('#parcelamento').hide();
   $('#parcelas').hide();
   $("input[name='parcela[]']").val('');
  }
 })
    
 $('#n-parcelas').on('change', function() {
  /*Calcular valor das parcelas (2x, 3x e 4x) e preencher inputs*/
 })
  
  
 });
```

```html
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Total R$</label></td>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="number" min="0" class="total" value="100" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="condicao-pag" id="condicao-pag">
        <td><label>Condição de pagamento:</label></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value=0>À vista</option>
                <option value=1>À prazo</option>
                <option value=2>Outros</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="parcelamento" style="display:none"> 
        <td>Parcelar em</td>
        <td>
            <select id="n-parcelas">
                <option></option>
                <option value="2" selected>2x</option>
                <option value="3">3x</option>
                <option value="4">4x</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id="parcelas" style="display:none">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="parcela[]" value="">
            <input type="date" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="parcela[]" value="">
            <input type="date" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: O resultado desse calculo é para aparecer onde? E qual é o calculo? Dá um exemplo sff

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wnm3jhr7/, nos inputs.

Comment: Você só precisa criar uma função que pegue o valor total e divida pelo número de parcelas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fiz uma função aqui para gerar o valor das parcelas e os inputs, roda ai. Espero ter ajudado. Comentei o código, qualquer duvida comente ai!!

```js
//Funcao para atualizar as parcelas e seus valores
 function atualizaValores(){
  // pegando a quantidade de parcelas
   var valor=$("#n-parcelas").val();

  //variavel que recebe os inputs(HTML)
   var geraInputs="";

  //Calculando o valor de cada parcela
   var valorParcela=parseFloat($(".total").val()/valor).toFixed(2);
  
  //gerando os inputs com os valores de cada parcela
   for(var i=0; i<valor;i++){
   geraInputs+="<td> <input type='text' name='parcela[]' value='"+valorParcela+"'>  <input type='date' value=''></td>";
   }

    // inserindo as parcelas 
    $("#parcelas").html(geraInputs);
   }

$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $(".total").on('change keyup keydown keypress',function(){
    // ao alterar o valor total, chama a funcao para alterar as parcelas
    atualizaValores();

  
  });
 $('#condicao-pag').on('change', 'select', function() {
  // ao alterar a condicao de pagamento,chama a funcao para alterar as parcelas
  atualizaValores();
  if($(this).val() == 1){
   $('#parcelamento').show();
   /*Calcular valor das parcelas (2x, 3x, 4x) e preencher inputs*/
   $('#parcelas').show();
  }
  else{
   $('#parcelamento').hide();
   $('#parcelas').hide();
   $("input[name='parcela[]']").val('');
  }
 })
    
 $('#n-parcelas').on('change', function() {
  /*Calcular valor das parcelas (2x, 3x, 4x) e preencher inputs*/
 //Ao alterar a quantidade e parcelas chama a funcao para alterar as parcelas
  atualizaValores();
 });
 
  
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><label>Total R$</label></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="total" value="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr name="condicao-pag" id="condicao-pag">
    <td><label>Condição de pagamento:</label></td>
    <td>
        <select/>
            <option value=0>À vista</option>
            <option value=1>À prazo</option>
            <option value=2>Outros</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="parcelamento" style="display:none"> 
    <td>Parcelar em</td>
    <td>
        <select id="n-parcelas">
            <option></option>
            <option value="2" selected>2x</option>
            <option value="3">3x</option>
            <option value="4">4x</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="parcelas" style="display:none">

  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Obrigado @localhost, exatamente o que estava precisando!

Answer (score 0):

Quase certo, só falta ajustar o detalhe das parcelas com dízima periódica, ou seja, se você tentar dividir 200,00 por 3 parcelas, do jeito que o código está vai dar 3x de 66,67 que dará um total de 200,01 e não 200,00.

O certo seria a primeira e a segunda parcela ficarem com 66,66 e a terceira 66,68.

Tô tentando resolver essa charada aqui.

Abs!

```js
//Funcao para atualizar as parcelas e seus valores
 function atualizaValores(){
  // pegando a quantidade de parcelas
   var valor=$("#n-parcelas").val();

  //variavel que recebe os inputs(HTML)
   var geraInputs="";

  //Calculando o valor de cada parcela
   var valorParcela=parseFloat($(".total").val()/valor).toFixed(2);
  
  //gerando os inputs com os valores de cada parcela
   for(var i=0; i<valor;i++){
   geraInputs+="<td> <input type='text' name='parcela[]' value='"+valorParcela+"'>  <input type='date' value=''></td>";
   }

    // inserindo as parcelas 
    $("#parcelas").html(geraInputs);
   }

$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $(".total").on('change keyup keydown keypress',function(){
    // ao alterar o valor total, chama a funcao para alterar as parcelas
    atualizaValores();

  
  });
 $('#condicao-pag').on('change', 'select', function() {
  // ao alterar a condicao de pagamento,chama a funcao para alterar as parcelas
  atualizaValores();
  if($(this).val() == 1){
   $('#parcelamento').show();
   /*Calcular valor das parcelas (2x, 3x, 4x) e preencher inputs*/
   $('#parcelas').show();
  }
  else{
   $('#parcelamento').hide();
   $('#parcelas').hide();
   $("input[name='parcela[]']").val('');
  }
 })
    
 $('#n-parcelas').on('change', function() {
  /*Calcular valor das parcelas (2x, 3x, 4x) e preencher inputs*/
 //Ao alterar a quantidade e parcelas chama a funcao para alterar as parcelas
  atualizaValores();
 });
 
  
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><label>Total R$</label></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" class="total" value="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr name="condicao-pag" id="condicao-pag">
    <td><label>Condição de pagamento:</label></td>
    <td>
        <select/>
            <option value=0>À vista</option>
            <option value=1>À prazo</option>
            <option value=2>Outros</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="parcelamento" style="display:none"> 
    <td>Parcelar em</td>
    <td>
        <select id="n-parcelas">
            <option></option>
            <option value="2" selected>2x</option>
            <option value="3">3x</option>
            <option value="4">4x</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="parcelas" style="display:none">

  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Só coloque a resposta depois de solucionado o problema. Não simplesmente declare que existe um problema e copie a solução de outro. Se houver grandes diferenças de resposta, com código de ideias diferentes, coloque uma nova resposta. Caso contrário, edite a resposta existente com a melhoria implementada - não edite por editar respostas com a solução aceita sem as melhorias!

Comment: Existe uma norma de tentar não reviver perguntas velhas, principalmente se já possuem resposta aceita. Quando muito, edite a resposta com ressalvas ou faça uma que tenha melhoria significativa. E no seu caso, você provavelmente fez duas respostas. Isso não condiz com as regras e provavelmente foi deletado o mais novo (sempre edite sua resposta se precisar). Tudo isso pode ser observado no "tour" e em páginas de ajuda e conduta. E o código funcional você pode colocar nessa resposta sua (clique no botão editar). Também não é correto ofender ninguém, OK? Sempre existe diálogo, bem como regras.

Comment: OK, José. Então eu encontro uma solução que está incorreta (100,00 dividido por 3 parcelas dá duas de 33,33 + 1 de 33,34 e não três de 33,33), corrijo o erro, posto aqui a solução e eu estou agindo errado? Já parou pra pensar no problema que um programador novado pode enfrentar se ele usar essa solução incorreta no e-commerce de um de seus clientes? Eu vi o erro, corrigi e vim aqui postar a correção porque pensei: "Alguém pode se ferrar se usar esse código sem a correção". Além disso, uma pergunta com menos de 1 ano não é velha. Me desculpe se o ofendi. Abs!

Comment: A quem possa interessar, aqui está mais uma vez o código CORRETO, como deve ser, colocando ou retirando as sobras na última parcela caso o resultado da divisão dê em dízima periódica:  fiddle.jshell.net/6b61L4z3/82